# Cannot get JQuery plugin working on Drupal 7

Tags: 7, javascript

I am trying to run a Jquery plugin QTip. The problem is that it is not running even though all the files are in the corect folders (plugin is both in info file and attched as a script below) and I took the code below from the plugin's website and pasted in the html section of WYSYWIG editor. Can anyone tell me why this is the case?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/bf/js/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

// Create the tooltips only on document load
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
// By suppling no content attribute, the library uses each elements title attribute by default
 $('#content a[href]').qtip({
  // Simply use an HTML img tag within the HTML string
  content: 'dfdfdfdfdf'
   });
});
// ]]></script>
<div id="content">
<a href="dddf.html">Why this not working</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the Drupal 7 upgrade guide](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#javascript_compatibility):

> Javascript should be made compatible with other libraries than jQuery
>   by adding a small wrapper around your existing code:

```
(function ($) {   
      // Original JavaScript code. 
})(jQuery);
```

> The $ global will no longer refer to the jquery object. However, with
>   this construction, the local variable $ will refer to jquery, allowing
>   your code to access jQuery through $ anyway, while the code will not
>   conflict with other libraries that use the $ global.

```
(function ($) {
  // Create the tooltips only on document load
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // By suppling no content attribute, the library uses each elements title attribute by default
    $('#content a[href]').qtip({
      // Simply use an HTML img tag within the HTML string
      content: 'dfdfdfdfdf'
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You can also change all the Dollar signs for "jQuery"

Comment: Thanks, I added the wrapper but still not working..

Comment: I'm leaning towards that its your WYSIWYG editor is the problem

Comment: Can you check in firebug if either script loads?

Answer (score 0):

By default Drupal 7 uses jQuery 1.4.4.  the  Qtip2 ( I assume you are using the latest Qtip) has a requirement of jQuery 1.6 and up. http://qtip2.com/guides

Install the jquery-update module https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update and set the front-end to the required version level for Qtip and you should  be ok.